How to implement a different header on each page with WordPress Waymore theme?
I am using the waymore theme of popularfx in WordPress and want to change the header image in my About and Service page.
Currently, the same header image is showing on all pages, but I want a different header banner on my About and Service page
I created header-about.php at wp-content/theme/popularfx/header-about.php
and changed code in page.php
<?php
    if(is_page('about'))
    {
       get_header('about');
    }
   else
   {
       get_header();
   }
  wp_head();
?>

but this code is not working at all.
I also tried different plugins for same unique header, wp header images etc

Did you check that your pages are using the "default" template, if not you need to make changes to the related template that is used. Also, note that wp_head(); should be in the header.php and header-about.php files, but not in page.php file.

On the page.php, try this:
<?php
   if ( is_page('about') ) {
       get_header('about');
   } elseif ( is_page('service') ) {
       get_header('service');
   } else {
       get_header(); 
   }
?>

Make sure you have both header-about.php and header-service.php for the respective pages if you want to customize both headers. The get_header('about') will call header-about.php.
Also, make sure to check that the page slug is 'about' e.g www.site-url.com/about for this is_page('about'). Or alternatively, check on the Permalinks settings in Settings > Permalinks to change the Permalinks settings appropriately.

I also tried this, but nothing happened, I think its due to theme,
